# Android Management API - Access Device Settings Issue

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, android-settings, android-management-api, cosu

I have an application that runs as a Kiosk app using the Android Management API. Inside the app is a hidden menu that is only accessible by pincode. Within this Hidden menu is an "Open Phone Settings" button which opens device settings.

I have enabled access to the settings as follows:

```
    "kioskCustomization": 
  {
    "statusBar": "SYSTEM_INFO_ONLY",
    "deviceSettings": "SETTINGS_ACCESS_ALLOWED",
    "systemErrorWarnings": "ERROR_AND_WARNINGS_ENABLED"
  },
```

This works for a period of time until a few months ago where it intermittently started to fail, providing no reason, but would continue to work after a quick reboot on affected devices. The issue has now progressed and the only way to access the settings of the device is to reboot into safe mode.

Does anybody have any experience with this or suggestions?

Comment: I tried replicating the issue using this app (com.apps.settings) for our kiosk and it works without issue. Can you give me the whole policy you’re using so that I can check if there is an error on your implementation.

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue. Could you find a fix for this?